# Monitor Threads using thread pool executor and create new thread if any of the thread gets killed automatically

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to look for some implementation of a thread pool executor in which.

1. I can have fixed number of threads
2. Each thread will infinitely run and perform some operation
3. If any threads gets killed by any way(either by system or because of some unexpected exception) I can get notification.
4. I can create new thread instead of the killed thread so that the task can continue gets executed.

I know how to create fixed thread pool executor service. I know how to get alive thread count using executor but is there any way I can get to know which thread gets killed so that I can create a new thread for that and make the task running.

Comment: The default ThreadPoolExecutor` does this. Why you need to do it yourself?

Comment: Can you please send some code snippet.

Comment: I didn't get your question. What kind of code snippet you are referring to?

Comment: As I mentioned:- I know how to create fixed thread pool executor service. I know how to get alive thread count using executor but is there any way I can get to know which thread gets killed so that I can create a new thread for that and make the task running